# Simultaneous CSS animation and spin transition

Tags: css, css-transitions, webkit-transform

```
<style> 
div
{
width:50px;
height:100px;
background:red;
position:relative;
animation:myfirst 5s infinite alternate;
-webkit-animation:myfirst 5s infinite alternate;
}

@keyframes myfirst
{
0%   { left:0px; top:0px;}
25%  { left:200px; top:0px;}
50%  { left:200px; top:200px;}
75%  { left:0px; top:200px;}
100% { left:0px; top:0px;}
}


@-webkit-keyframes myfirst 
{
0%   { left:0px; top:0px;}
25%  { left:200px; top:0px;}
50%  { left:200px; top:200px;}
75%  { left:0px; top:200px;}
100% { left:0px; top:0px;}
}


</style>


<body>

<div></div>

</body>
```

Is it possible to add some sort of a rotate transition to this? I've tried adding the code to the div declaration and creating another selector, none of these appeared to work.

Comment: What do you exactly mean by *continuous spin transition*?

Comment: sorry, i phrased that wrong. basically, where the box rotates 360deg infinitely.

Comment: Like [this](http://jsbin.com/isinel/1)?

Comment: Then you'd better create a different animation for that. I will add this as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add and define another animation, perhaps like so:

```
@keyframes rotate
{
from {
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
to { 
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}
```

And then add the animation to your element, separating it with a comma:

```
animation:myfirst 5s infinite alternate, rotate 2.5s linear infinite;
```

In this example note the following things:

1. `2.5s` I chose this to make two complete rotation in one go of your first animation, I thought it looked smoother.
2. `linear` gives you the feeling of endless rotation in the void. Try other functions if you don't want this effect.
3. I didn't put `alternate` because we want the element to spin continuously.

<kbd>[**Demonstration**](http://jsbin.com/isinel/4)</kbd>